# ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys

Tags: php

```
$connection = ssh2_connect("myHost", 22);
```

Getting error : **ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys**

I am tryig to conect SFTP through HOST and a PORT getting error on

```
ssh2_connect
```

Fuction : *ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys*